# Ruby populate 2 dim array dynamically

Tags: ruby

I'm working on parser to analyze SQL code so trying to deal with all block comments. I come up with solution to process regex by index to see if it's inside comment block and for this purpose trying to fill 2 dim array in the code below where second element will be literal let say **s**. Not sure if this doable. I tried one gem but it failed.
My goal to get array filled like

`all =[[9,'s'],[19,'s'],[24,'s']]`
referring to example below. Final goal is to process legacy SQL code (a lot of it..) to find active lines with specific keywords.  Best

```
x = 'line:xss /*   */   /*   /*  CODE_Comment */  '
     puts x

    i = -1
    all = [[],[]]
    while i = x.index('/*',i+1)             
do   all << i   ####<@>>< how to add literal to second element ???
    end
    puts all
```

Comment: you can initialise 'all' as [] (an array) and then insert arrays into it.  There is no special initialisation needed to make it 2 dimensional.  To make a 2d array create a 1d array, then put an array (or multiple arrays) inside it.

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly which bits of x you want in your array, or what the nubers in your array are representing, but to add an 's' after I you'd do  all << [i,'s']

Comment: Tx Will. it's solved). I Just need to deal with Indexes for each occurrence of regex, and it's should be for each line

Comment: "it failed" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following.

```
str = 'line:xss /*   */   /*   /*  CODE_Comment */  '
```

```
str.gsub(/\/\*/).with_object([]) { |_,a| a << [Regexp.last_match.begin(0), 's'] }
  #=> [[9, "s"], [19, "s"], [24, "s"]]
```

The steps are as follows.

```
enum1 = str.gsub(/\/\*/)
  #=> #<Enumerator: "line:xss /*   */   /*   /*  CODE_Comment */  "
  #     :gsub(/\/\*/)>
```

If you examine the doc for [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) you will see that when `gsub` has a single argument and no block (the 4<sup>th</sup> form of the method) it returns an enumerator. Curiously, when used in this way it has nothing to do with substituting substrings with other substrings.

`enum1` does nothing more than generate matches:

```
enum1.next #=> "/*" 
enum1.next #=> "/*" 
enum1.next #=> "/*" 
enum1.next #=> StopIteration (iteration reached an end)
```

See [Enumerator#next](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-next). Before continuing, let's reset the enumerator:

```
enum1.rewind
```

See [Enumerator#rewind](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-rewind). Next,

```
enum2 = enum1.with_object([])
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: "line:xss /*   */   /*   /*  CODE_Comment */  "
  #     :gsub(/\/\*/)>:with_object([])> 
enum2.next #=> ["/*", []] 
enum2.next #=> ["/*", []] 
enum2.next #=> ["/*", []] 
enum2.next #=> StopIteration (iteration reached an end) 
enum2.rewind
```

`enum2` (which can be thought of as a *compound enumerator*) now generates elements which it passes to the block. The values of those elements are captured by the block variables and then the block calculation is performed. We can add some `puts` statements to examine the values that are computed.

```
enum2.each do |_,a|
  puts "\n_ = #{_}, a = #{a}"
  md = Regexp.last_match
  b= md.begin(0) 
  puts "md = #{md}, b = #{b}"
  a << [b, 's']
  puts "a = #{a}"
end
  #=> [[9, "s"], [19, "s"], [24, "s"]]
```

and prints

```
_ = /*, a = []
md = /*, b = 9
a = [[9, "s"]]

_ = /*, a = [[9, "s"]]
md = /*, b = 19
a = [[9, "s"], [19, "s"]]

_ = /*, a = [[9, "s"], [19, "s"]]
md = /*, b = 24
a = [[9, "s"], [19, "s"], [24, "s"]]
```

I have used an underscore (a valid local variable) as a placeholder for the first block variable to signify to the reader that it is not used in the block calculation (a commonly-used convention). To construct the array we need the offset in the string `str` where this match was made. For that we first obtain the `MatchData` instance generated by that match (see [Regexp::last_match](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Regexp.html#method-c-last_match)) and then use the method [LastMatch#begin](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/MatchData.html#method-i-begin) to obtain the offset for the beginning of the match. Lastly, we append the desired 2-element array to `a`.

The value of `Regexp.last_match` is held by the global variable `$~`, so that variable is sometimes used in place of `Regexp.last_match`.